# NameError: name 'vk' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Возникла проблема помогите решить

```py
import vk as vk
import vk_api
import COVID19Py
import datetime
import time

    while True: # Запуск бесконечного цикла
        bot = vk_api.VkApi(token="c0f8f8db96c59439caf6bbc45fc4f359384f0011781224373c2ad4ac8eaf53293695cbed7d02") # Инициализируем сессию бота ВКонтакте через токен
        covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19() # Инициализируем бота COVID19
        location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("RU") # Инициализируем нужную вам локацию для получения статистики
        info = "Заболевших Covid-19 в России: " + str(location[0]['latest']['confirmed']) # Записиваем статус в переменную info
        vk.method("status.set", {"text": info}) # Выполняем смену статуса
        time.sleep(60000) # Программа "засыпает" на 10 минут
```

ошибка: `NameError: name 'vk' is not defined`

Comment: Во-первых, в какой строке ошибка-то? Во-вторых, как называется ваш файл? В-третьих, не боитесь, что кто-нибудь возьмёт ваш токен и начнёт рассылать через вашего бота всякие гадости?

Comment: `import vk as vk` зачем это?:

Comment: @andreymal  File "C:\Users\last pick saport\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    vk.method("status.set", {"text": info}) # Выполняем смену статуса
NameError: name 'vk' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы избежать ошибки NameError: name 'vk' is not defined, вам необходимо:

- pip3 install vk -- user - прописать обычную команду, вдруг вы ее не установили.Э
- 1 строка (import vk as vk) заменить на import vk, а вообще рекомендую все импорты писать в одну строку (import vk, vk_api, COVID19Py, datetime, time)
- Рекомендую изменить Ваш токен, для избежания несанкционированного использования бота.

Comment: Я не согласен с вашим 2 советом, для лучшей читабельности кода рекомендуется каждую библиотеку импортировать с новой строки.

Comment: Но та же самая оптимизация кода слегка увеличивается. Тем более у него пока в коде мало строк, а значит можно читабельностью пренебречь.